# Will NEST project in elasticsearch or in the client?

Tags: c#, performance, elasticsearch, nest, dto

If I have a complex document indexed in elasticsearch and query it using a DTO, will a projection for the fields required by the DTO be applied in elasticsearch, before sending the data to the C# client or will the full source be sent, and C# will use that to hydrate the DTO?

`var response = await elasticClient.SearchAsync<TDto>(searchRequest);`

Basically, I need to know if I can simply ask for a `TDto` and not worry about data volume of the larger `ComplexDocument` that was indexed, or if I have to specify `Source` inclusion/exclusion in the `searchRequest` to get the best performance.

Comment: Have you tried it? NEST is a pretty simple library, so I'd *expect* they would send your request exactly as you provide it and would not do any kind of automatic field selection.

Comment: @StephenCleary No I didn't try it. Setting up the test scenario with inspection etc takes time. I usually ask questions that get no response because they're "hard" questions. So I figured I'd ask an "easy" question and see if SO can be of help. Surely somebody must know the answer to this, I figure..

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is that NEST will retrieve the entire document and then do projection on the client. But not sure enough to make this comment into an answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Elasticsearch will send back the full `_source` document for each search hit. You can specify which fields of `_source` to include/exclude with [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-source-filtering)

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var searchResponse = client.Search<ComplexDocument>(s => s
    .Source(sf => sf
        .Includes(i => i
            .Field(f => f.Path)
            .Field(f => f.Content)
        )
        .ExcludeAll()
    )
);

foreach(var source in searchResponse.Documents)
{
    var path = source.Path;
}
```

which sends

```
{
    "_source": {
        "excludes": ["*"],
        "includes": ["path", "content"]
    }
}
```

Or you can ask not to return `_source` at all

```cs
var searchResponse = client.Search<ComplexDocument>(s => s
    .Source(false)
);
```

With source filtering, the storage field for `_source` is read completely on the Elasticsearch side, and filtering applied. This is usually fine, but if `_source` is a **huge** document, and you only ever want to return a subset of fields in response to a search, you might decide to use [stored fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-stored-fields) instead.

As the name implies, stored fields are fields stored separately to `_source` (by specifying `store:true` in their mapping) and can be returned in a search response

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<ComplexDocument>(s => s
    .StoredFields(f => f
        .Field(ff => ff.Path)
    )
);

foreach(var fields in searchResponse.Fields)
{
    var path = fields.ValueOf<ComplexDocument, string>(f => f.Path);
}
```

Stored fields are returned in a `"fields"` property on each hit.

> If I have a complex document indexed in elasticsearch and query it
>   using a DTO, will a projection for the fields required by the DTO be
>   applied in elasticsearch, before sending the data to the C# client or
>   will the full source be sent, and C# will use that to hydrate the DTO?

In summary, Elasticsearch will return the full `_source` and NEST will map matching properties in the `_source` to properties of the DTO. NEST [maps camel case properties in JSON to the POCO properties by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/field-inference.html#camel-casing). If you want to transmit less across the wire, take a look at source filtering. You could probably wrap up the functionality to include only fields in the DTO in the request as an extension method to `SearchDescriptor<TInferDocument>`

```cs
public class ComplexDocument
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public Attachment Attachment { get; set; }
}

public class SimpleDTO
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

public static class SearchDescriptorExtensions
{
    public static SearchDescriptor<TInferDocument> SourceIncludesDto<TInferDocument, TDocument>(this SearchDescriptor<TInferDocument> descriptor) 
        where TInferDocument : class
        where TDocument : class
        {
            // TODO: cache this :)
            Fields fields = typeof(TDocument).GetProperties();

            return descriptor.Source(s => s
                .Includes(f => f
                    .Fields(fields)
                )
            );
        }
}

ISearchResponse<SimpleDTO> searchResponse = 
    client.Search<ComplexDocument, SimpleDTO>(s => s
        .SourceIncludesDto<ComplexDocument, SimpleDTO>()
    );
```

sends

```cs
{
    "_source": {
        "includes": ["path"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks! :) I cannot use stored fields, as I'll have to search some of that data even if I don't need it returned in all cases. The extension method approach seems promissing. I assume I'll have to expand on it if I want to include only parts of nested types. But this is a very good starting point.